# Milliseconds in Lap Time Average dropping the Zero in Tenths place

Tags: javascript

I am using code I found on this site to average lap times in MM:SS.mmm ([Averaging Times using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469903/averaging-times-using-javascript))

It works great until the result has a zero in the tenths place. For example, the result should be 01:00.096 however, the zero is dropped and the answer is 01:00.96

I have simplified the input of 'times' to highlight the problem.

I have looked at different formatting issues, tried converting the strings to numbers and I've looked at the `offsetify` function thinking it was somehow interpreting the milliseconds incorrectly.

I am a novice at JavaScript with no formal training but enjoy hobby-programming.  I have learned a lot from the examples on this site for use in my own little apps.

```
var times = ['01:00.096'];
var date = 0
var result = '';                        

function offsetify(t)
{
    return t < 10 ? '0' + t : t;
}

for(var x = 0; x < times.length; x++ ) {
    var tarr = times[x].split(':');
    date += new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, tarr[0], tarr[1].split('.')[0], tarr[1].split('.')[1]).getTime();                  
}
var avg = new Date(date/times.length);
result = offsetify(avg.getMinutes()) + ':' + offsetify(avg.getSeconds()) + '.' + offsetify(avg.getMilliseconds());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `offsetify(t)` appends a `0` in case your minutes/seconds is only single-digit - however milliseconds should be 3 digits!

You could create a new function that appends `0` if it is already 2 digits (less than 100), and `00` if it is only single-digit (less than 10) and just returns the result if it is already 3 digits.

```
function offsetifyMilliseconds(t)
{
  return t < 10 ? '00' + t : t < 100 ? '0' + t : t;
}
```

and then do

```
result = offsetify(avg.getMinutes()) + ':' + offsetify(avg.getSeconds()) + '.' + offsetifyMilliseconds(avg.getMilliseconds());
```

However recent versions of Javascript (from ES2017) has access to the `.padStart()` function on any string:

> The padStart() method pads the current string with another string (multiple times, if needed) until the resulting string reaches the given length. The padding is applied from the start (left) of the current string.
>
> -- [String.prototype.padStart() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Using this would make your code much more readable (although you'd have to convert the numeric result to a string first). You could even change your `offsetify` function to use this method, and prevent code duplication!

In the example below I have defined 2 as the default padding length for the method, but you can pass an additional parameter to the function when you want to use it for milliseconds:

```js
var times = ['01:00.096'];
var date = 0
var result = '';                        

function offsetify(t, len = 2)
{
    return t.toString().padStart(len, '0');
}

for(var x = 0; x < times.length; x++ ) {
    var tarr = times[x].split(':');
    date += new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, tarr[0], tarr[1].split('.')[0], tarr[1].split('.')[1]).getTime();                  
}
var avg = new Date(date/times.length);

var minutes = offsetify(avg.getMinutes());
var seconds = offsetify(avg.getSeconds());
var milliseconds = offsetify(avg.getMilliseconds(), 3);

result = minutes + ':' + seconds + ':' + milliseconds;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Watch out for single-digit values in your custom code: "5" would be "05" but you want "005". Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see the 0 dropping is because in the offsetify function you have

```
return t < 10 ? '0' + t : t;
```

and you are passing it the value 96, which is not less than 10, so the function returns `96`.

If you are able to find a datetime-formatting library like [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) or [moment](https://momentjs.com/), and you should use one, then great! Let the library do the work for you.

If you would like the practice, which is great for learning, use

```
s.padStart(3, '0')
```

for milliseconds, and

```
s.padStart(2, '0')
```

for minutes. For example, for your milliseconds:

```
> "5".padStart(3, "0")
'005'
> "55".padStart(3, "0")
'055'
> "383".padStart(3, "0")
'383'
```